# Edit CSS in browser using Chrome Inspector & Workspace, have changes stay on refresh of page

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I mapped my local CSS file to the live web page I am trying to edit in the Google Inspector Workspace. Sure I can save my edits to my local CSS file in the sources tab but that does not keep the edits on the live page. Is there any way to make the CSS changes you enter into the inspector stay on the live page even if you refresh the page? I keep getting to a place where the page is setup how I want it and then I lose all of my work on the page and its a pain to set it all back up. I have tried the Chrome extensions that state they do this but none of them work when I click on the extension icon that it creates. If there is a free way to get this done I appreciate the help.

I do not have access to the HTML file, my client only sent me the live page URL and wants me to edit it using only my local CSS file. I need a way to be able to do this and see the live edits stay on the page as I make them.

Answer (score 3):

You can save your CSS changes from Chrome Dev Tools itself. Chrome now allows you to add local folders to your Workspace. After allowing Chrome access to the folder and adding the folder to the local workspace, you can map a web resource to a local resource.

Navigate to the Sources panel of the Developer Tools, Right-click in the left panel (where the files are listed) and select Add Folder to Workspace. You can get to a stylesheet in the Sources panel quickly by clicking the stylesheet at the top-right of each CSS rule for a selected element in the Elements panel.

[image]

After adding the folder, you'll have to give Chrome access to the folder. Allow chrome access
Next, you need to map the network resource to the local resource.
enter image description here

[image]

After reloading the page, Chrome now loads the local resources for the mapped files. To make things simpler, Chrome only shows you the local resources (so you don't get confused on as to whether you are editing the local or the network resource). To save your changes, press CTRL + S when editing the file.

Comment: Yeah...I already did that is what I said in the first sentence up in my question. It does not show my CSS local file edits on the page when I refresh...That is what I want to do and I am wondering why it will not show my local CSS edits on the page on refresh or after I set it...

Comment: I think you may have to force a refresh of the page.  Try pressing Shift + click the refresh button let me know if that works.

Comment: That did not work using the Shift + click, how is it this hard to connect a local css file to this thing? I even cleared the cache and all of that using the network panel.

Comment: Are you ensuring that you are saving the changes by pressing CTRL +S after editing?

Comment: Yep, and i can see them come through right away in Sublime text after i load that up. This is so odd.

Comment: For the HTML file in the sources tab it does give an error that says 404 failed to load resource, but I don't get that when it has the HTML in the elements view?  Should that even matter?

Comment: I know this is a bad answer but possibly try to re-set it up? It should be working I have tested from my end as well

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to save your CSS file changes by adding it to your workspace like you've mentioned in your question. This is what the Chrome documentation states and how you can do it.

[Set Up Persistence with DevTools Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow)

It may seem like a silly question, but are you saving the files? Also worth noting the limitation (taken from the above link)...

As powerful as Workspaces are, there are some limitations you should be aware of.

> - ***Only style changes in the Elements panel are persisted; changes to    the DOM are not persisted.***
> - ***Only styles defined in an external CSS file can be saved. Changes to element.style or to inline styles are    not persisted. (If
>     you have inline styles, they can be changed on the    Sources
>     panel.)***
> - Style changes in the Elements panel are persisted    immediately without an explicit save -- Ctrl + S or Cmd + S (Mac) --    if you
>     have the CSS resource mapped to a local file.
> - If you are    mapping files from a remote server instead of a local server, when    you refresh the page, Chrome reloads the page from the
>     remote server.
> - Your changes still persist to disk and are reapplied if you continue    editing in Workspaces. You must use the full path to a
>     mapped file in    the browser. Even your index files must include
>     .html in the URL, in    order to see the staged version.

Comment: Well i did it how they say to do it and when i hit refresh it does not have my changes. It will only save them to my local file in the sources tab if I manually enter them in after the fact, nothing I do in the elements tab will save or stay on refresh and that is my objective here.